# Is it ok and not breaching copyright to add a slogan onto original business logo?

Tags: logo, copyright, branding

On behalf of a company he works for, a family friend has asked me to add a commemorative slogan onto the bottom of their original logo. They don't want me to alter the logo in any way, just add the slogan.

I was just wondering if this was ok to do, as I am not changing or updating any of the original designers work for this company's logo, just adding on something to sit underneath it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The copyright almost certainly belongs to the company that commissioned the logo, not the person who designed it, so they can probably do whatever they want to / with it. However, I’m not an IP lawyer and I don’t know the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Depends on the copyrights restrictions that were linked to the design by the designer and in which country you are living. E.g. in Germany a small change that does not reach the "threshold of originality" is just considered an adjustment and new negotiations for new copyright transfers are not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

> On behalf of a company he works for

The copyright holder is free to request anyone to make changes to the work they own.

Think of the copyright like a house. As the homeowner you can request anyone paint your house. There's nothing wrong with that. But a neighbor can't hire someone to paint your house without your permission.

While not impossible, it would be *exceptionally* rare that a company does not own the copyright to their own logo.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it is not an alteration to the logo, you should be okay. In your question though, you say, "onto the bottom of the original logo." as if it were a square or rectangle you are adding it on to. And, in that case, the answer is no. Then it would change the original integrity of the logo design, making it a logo modification. An updated tag line is generally no interference to the logo design.